# "Cloning" a corpus in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I'm attempting to create my own corpus in NLTK. I've been reading some of the documentation on this and it seems rather complicated... all I wanted to do is "clone" the movie reviews corpus but with my own text. Now, I know I can just change files in the move reviews corpus to my own... but that limits me to working with just one such corpus at a time (ie. I'd have to continually be swapping files). is there any way i could just clone the movie reviews corpus?

thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie reviews are read with the `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader` class. Use it directly to load your corpus. The following should work for an exact copy of the movies corpus:

```
mr = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(path_to_your_reviews, r'(?!\.).*\.txt',
        cat_pattern=r'(neg|pos)/.*')
```

Whatever maches inside `cat_pattern` are the categories: In this case, `neg` and `pos`. If your corpus has different categories (e.g., movie genres rather than positive/negative evaluations), change the directory structure and adjust the `cat_pattern` parameter to match.

PS. For categorized corpora with different structure, the nltk offers a wealth of ways to specify the category; read the documentation of `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you a define a new corpus by copying the definition of `movie_reviews` in `nltk.corpus`? You can do this all you want with new directories, and then copy the directory structure and replace the files.